# Tutorial or recipes to handle previous and current "page" in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for advice, some recipe or the link to a good tutorial about how handle the page a user visit in my site, so I can, in any moment, redirect him to the original page where he was, (for example after login). I want to learn "the right, rails way" to do this.

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [post](http://joshsharpe.com/archives/redirect-back-or-default-youre-probably-doing-it-wrong) might get you started.